# Replacing part of pattern with sed

Tags: sed

I'm looking to replace a `space` that always comes after a number with a `|` in the middle of a pattern. There are also similar patterns later in the line sometimes that I do not wish to replace (see first/second lines in the examples).

example:

```
12315 asdfea 1 1ffesa
45456 asefasef 1 era
12 asfase
4 4aefs
```

what I need:

```
12315|asdfea 1 1ffesa
45456|asefasef 1 era
12|asfase
4|4aefs
```

I have tried this:

```
 sed 's/\([0-9][ ][a-zA-Z]\)/|/g' file.txt
```

However this deletes the pattern such that it looks like this:

```
|sdfea 1 1ffesa
|sefasef 1 era
|sfase
|4aefs
```

Which is not what I need.

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given sample input/output,

```
$ sed 's/ /|/' file.txt
12315|asdfea 1 1ffesa
45456|asefasef 1 era
12|asfase
4|4aefs
```

By default, only first match will be replaced. `g` modifier will replace all matches

To replace first matched space between a digit and alphabet (matching [depends on locale too](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Locale-Considerations))

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1|\2/' file.txt
12315|asdfea 1 1ffesa
45456|asefasef 1 era
12|asfase
4 4aefs
```

This uses [capture group and backreferences](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions). Note that last line is not modified

Comment: This works, last line can be replaced if you add 0-9 in the second pattern. so [a-zA-Z0-9]. Thanks!